# How do i decide initial population and chromosomes in genetic algorithm for image processing?

Tags: genetic-algorithm

I am new to image processing and GA as well. After searching, i got an idea about how GA works. Now i have a situation where i had to apply GA on images. When i searched about it i could not figure out what is the population and chromosomes...but where ever i searched they say take 1-D or 2-D array as chromosomes and find its fitness value.I am finding it difficult to understand these statement. please help me to define initial population (is it the whole image or any part of image? and the chromosomes . Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is your idea of using GA in image processing? Do you intend to use it for image segmentation or something else? Please , provide more information?

Comment: i am first planning to implement for image enhancement .

Comment: In order to evolve your gene pool you have to be able quantify your solution(s). How would that apply to image enhancement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you have issues on terminology: chromosomes are the individuals that you are using to explore the space of solutions, population is the set of those chromosomes (individuals).

In a GA, you can represent a solution as a string. In your case, a solution will be an image, probably composed by pixels.

You can think as those pixels as the DNA of the image. Therefore, that DNA is your image 'chromosome'. In other word, a chromosome is the sequence of pixels in your image.

Now, as you know, in GA you combine selection, crossover and mutation to (hopefully) get better solutions to your problem (e.g. better images).

To apply those 3 operators, you need a population, that is, a collection of chromosomes, that you will randomly sample, combine and mutate. Once you did these 3 operation, you will obtain a new population, that normally replaces the old one.

I hope this clarifies.

### EDIT

Using one "chromosome" for each row is not quite right if you want to evolve multiple images (or better: it depends). You have to think to your individuals (image) as single-chromosomed (human beings have many chromosomes, but in GA and GP usually you have only one for each individual).

The hierarchy is:

- a *population* is composed by *multiple individuals*
- an *individual* has a single *chromosome* (DNA)
- each *chromosome* is composed by multiple *genes*

A *gene* is something that you consider the smallest mutable unit. So, for example, if your mutation operation can change a single pixel at time, your genes will be pixels (for a 256x256 image, you get 65536 genes).

You can also use entire rows as genes, in that way, a chromosome would be composed by 256 genes, and each gene will be an array of 256 pixels. Usually this means that you cannot break a single row using crossover, but crossover will mix the lines of two images.

What you pick to be genes depends on your application. You could also represent a 256x256 RGB (24bit) image as a chromosome of 256*256*3 bytes, where each gene is a byte or as a 256*256*24 bits, where each gene is a bit.

Deciding what you can use as a gene is how you define how small can be a change and where you can cut the chromosome when you do crossover.

Sadly, there is not an unique vision for the terminology. Many scientists have different visions on what a "gene" is, or what a "genome" is, or how you can define a "fitness" function. Anyway, you just have to learn the basic concepts: mapping them to names will be easier later, don't worry :)

You may want to check out this: http://www.boente.eti.br/fuzzy/ebook-fuzzy-mitchell.pdf

Comment: thank you AkiRoss......Now i will write ehat i understood from your answer just check whether it is right. if i take an image of 256X256 pixels ,i can take first row as one Chromosome(collection of pixels(DNA)).. and similarly second row, third row as another chromosomes. This collections of chromosomes

Comment: [edit continuation]  forms the population. Then with the chromosomes obtained(row arrays) we cross-over and mutate to generate another set of arrays which forms another population.  we then iterate these process to get our desired results.  Is my reasoning right?

Comment: oh.... now I get it...so one image = one chromosome and each row = a gene ( which is a collection of pixels) similarly another image is an another chromosome. We crossover these two chromosomes(images) to form a new image (chromosome).. is it right now? ..... and more over i must get hold of basics first...but that link is not working for me.can u please tell me the name of the book or article.

Comment: Yes, that is a correct view, but *not the only one*. Remember that you decide what genes and chromosome are depending on your application. The book is "An Introduction to Genetic Algorithms" by Melanie Mitchell. Also, the Wikipedia page is rather well written: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm (note: on wikipedia terminology is different, but concepts are the same)

Answer (score 1):

With what do you plan to enhance the images? If you are going to apply operations like filters, blur, etc. Then the chromosome could have the parameters of such operations: type of filter, kernel size, you can even code all the values of the kernel. You could also use GP instead of GA: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.112.4452&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Thank you Enrique Arriaga ... but i am asked to implement in GA.

Answer (score 0):

GA is global optimization heuristic. First you should clear for yourself what exactly you will optimize. One way to form initial population is by generating random individuals.

Comment: What if some of the generated individuals in the initial population are repetitive? Is this a problem? Should it be avoided?

Comment: Usually it is not a problem, but if you put extra efforts you can make individuals unique.